# how to send key[op]:value using axios params in js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, query-string

For example -
axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/v1/stocks/${params.id}`,
{
params: {
search: searchKeyword,
**cost[gte]: 300**
}
}
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the param with [] in quotes:

```
{ params: { search: searchKeyword, "cost[gte]": 300 }
```